# how to create custom php.ini To access curl_exec

Tags: php

i found error on my site

Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/fullfree/public_html/12host/my/new/login.php on line 207

i was trying to find solution on internet than i was found the real problem All people say Change ypur php.ini file but my hosting provider not Give me Php.ini file please tell me how to create custom php.ini To access curl_exec
Thanks

Comment: ask your hosting provider

Comment: Move to a better hosting

Comment: If your hosting provider has disabled it, a) they're idiots and b) you can't override it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change your php.ini file on shared hosting (which I presume you have) I suggest switching to another hosting provider that allowes cURL.

Comment: my hosting provider give me some steps please can you check this its work in this or not
http://support.zen.co.uk/kb/KnowledgebaseArticle.aspx?articleid=11463

Comment: Never heard of something like that but check this url for the php.ini file download it and upload it to the given directory, maybe it will work https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production

Comment: @Riyaz3862555 So their article is telling you to create a php.ini file inside */public_html* ... i.e. the docroot?! **Really** get a better hosting provider!

Comment: error fix i just follow hosting provider steps maybe its work good

Comment: can you modify my facebook auto like Script I got this script by my Facebook Friend

Comment: i just put curl_exec = on on php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

You can try PHP fsockopen() - it might be allowed by your provider.

Comment: Can you tell me how to setup this